# No index.html file after gatsby-cli build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm experimenting with GatsbyJS. I created a new site derived from their default site generator and made some changes. When using the `gatsby develop` command everything works as expected. I went to use `gatsby build` and it does produce a /public folder, however there's no "index.html" or even "bundle.js"

Is the default site "special" in that it won't produce a site the typical way? Is there another setting needed in the gatsby-config version to produce index.html?

A `ls` of the /public directory returns:

```
1-5cf9b126c8aa029e3c76.js
1-5cf9b126c8aa029e3c76.js.map
1-f2577b7d9227c6ab20bd.js
1-f2577b7d9227c6ab20bd.js.map
404
app-dc0da5ea76a79bd92e99.js
app-dc0da5ea76a79bd92e99.js.map
app-e2d084d7f150c4a0d4f4.js
app-e2d084d7f150c4a0d4f4.js.map
chunk-map.json
component---node-modules-gatsby-plugin-offline-app-shell-js-896a3f852b233b9ca05e.js
component---node-modules-gatsby-plugin-offline-app-shell-js-896a3f852b233b9ca05e.js.map
component---src-pages-404-js-8e1643e05587f89c70d6.js
component---src-pages-404-js-8e1643e05587f89c70d6.js.map
component---src-pages-404-js-c2122e5847e5d16ffe11.js
component---src-pages-404-js-c2122e5847e5d16ffe11.js.map
component---src-pages-index-js-be99ef46e818d68362b3.js
component---src-pages-index-js-be99ef46e818d68362b3.js.map
component---src-pages-index-js-edad0a6dd0d36ec7cdbd.js
component---src-pages-index-js-edad0a6dd0d36ec7cdbd.js.map
component---src-pages-page-2-js-0479e3779ff85cb5431c.js
component---src-pages-page-2-js-0479e3779ff85cb5431c.js.map
component---src-pages-page-2-js-a49a481686ec152c45b7.js
component---src-pages-page-2-js-a49a481686ec152c45b7.js.map
icons
manifest.webmanifest
offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback
pages-manifest-5c619b10fb87f94c2d85.js
pages-manifest-5c619b10fb87f94c2d85.js.map
pages-manifest-e84c50768dd42edc85fe.js
pages-manifest-e84c50768dd42edc85fe.js.map
render-page.js
render-page.js.map
static
styles-0375cdcc38b87565858c.js
styles-0375cdcc38b87565858c.js.map
styles-b76dfad3fcff2976e17c.js
styles-b76dfad3fcff2976e17c.js.map
styles.fc4fa5e094d218207796.css
webpack-runtime-50855368c384639cab1f.js
webpack-runtime-50855368c384639cab1f.js.map
webpack-runtime-66b8792cf68b5ba07ac4.js
webpack-runtime-66b8792cf68b5ba07ac4.js.map
webpack.stats.json
```

For reference:

```
$ gatsby -v
2.5.5
```

And the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.3.5",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.37",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.26",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.32",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.28",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.17",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create it and what were the changes?

Comment: `gatsby new site` and I made some new components to replace a default one

Comment: I'd try removing the `node_modules` folder and trying `npm install` again. Also, can you post your `packages.json` file?

Comment: I added `package.json`. Reinstalling the node files had no effect...

Comment: Running `gatsby develop` did create a new index.html, but that's weird.

Comment: Ah I found it. There was an error. For some reason you can call 'fetch' just fine when in `develop` mode, but it needs to be imported when running `build`

Comment: Nice, glad you find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments above the problem was that `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` seemed to have different requirements. While working with the `bulld` command es6's `fetch` command needs to be imported manually (boo).

This just meant adding the line

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

To all files calling `fetch`.

Comment: glad you got it sorted out, `gatsby build` generate pages in node environment meaning it doesn't have access to the browser-only `window` object. This includes stuff like `fetch`, `location`, `document`... etc. If you meant to use `fetch` only in the browser, you have to check for `window` like `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`; otherwise you have to manually import a package (like you've found out).